# Calling a Ptoaster function within a Tkinter GUI class

Tags: python, tkinter

### The Problem

I'm working on a **Python GUI**, using **Tkinter**. I'm also trying to add "toaster" messages, using **Ptoaster**. Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```py
from tkinter import *
import ptoaster

PADDING = 20

class MyInterface:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.label = self.make_label()
        print_welcome()

    def make_label(self):
        result = Label(self.root, text="Hello, world!")
        result.pack(padx=PADDING, pady=PADDING)
        return result

    def run_me(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

def print_welcome():
    message = "Hello again!"
    ptoaster.notify("Hello!", message)

interface = MyInterface()
interface.run_me()
```

If I try to run the above code, one of two things will happen:

1. The command line will spit out the following error:

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python3: ../../src/xcb_io.c:260: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
XIO:  fatal IO error 25 (Inappropriate ioctl for device) on X server ":0"
      after 207 requests (207 known processed) with 2 events remaining.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

2. My whole laptop will **freeze**, necessitating a hard reset.

However, if I move the call `print_welcome()` from outside of MyInterface, so that it's called before this class is initialised, then none of the above errors crop up.

### What I'd Like to Know

1. How to call a function, from within a Tkinter GUI class, which causes a "toaster" message to be displayed, without causing the whole platform to crash.
2. Why the above errors are cropping up.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation states it needs to be verified that the `ptoaster.notify` is called from the main program.

> IMPORTANT - you need to make sure you call notify from the main program

Working code for me:

```
from tkinter import *
import ptoaster

PADDING = 20

class MyInterface:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.label = self.make_label()
        print_welcome()

    def make_label(self):
        result = Label(self.root, text="Hello, world!")
        result.pack(padx=PADDING, pady=PADDING)
        return result

    def run_me(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

def print_welcome():
    message = "Hello again!"
    ptoaster.notify("Hello!", message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    interface = MyInterface()
    interface.run_me()
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/ptoaster) (See: Sample Program)

Comment: Forgive me if I'm being stupid, but you only seem to have made an inconsequential change to the last few lines of my code. In any case, when I save your code into its own file and run it with `python3 nagyl.py`, I get the same error as before, on both my laptops. Ubuntu is the OS on both my machines, if that makes any difference. **TL;DR Not calling `ptoaster` from the main program doesn't seem to be the issue in this case.**

Comment: @TomHosker It was perfectly fine on my machine! Without the line I added, the toaster did not pop up. I though that created some sort of a problem at your side. I suggest updating your module versions, it might be a compatibility issue. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: No need to delete your answer. You can hardly be held responsible for not having a laptop which is mis-configured in all the ways that mine is! In fact, I'll give you an upvote for an answer which may well be useful for someone in a similar situation to myself. I'll check if my packages need updating, and get back to you if I find anything interesting.

Comment: @TomHosker Thanks! We could compare versions if it is needed.